# UWP Application deployment and package signing for distribution

Tags: desktop-application, packaging, winui-3, uno-platform

We have a UWP application developed using winui3/winappsdk build on top of Uno Platform which needs to be packaged and distributed to customers. while publishing from visual studio it requires a certificate with digital signature for which we have provided self signed certificate. However when deploying/installing application msix package in other machines it still says untrusted application and cant install the package.

we tried generating the certificate using onecert portal but looks like the cert cant be used coz the cert has different purpose for client authorization than digital signature. how to generate a cert which has only digital signature and what is the correct process to sign and distribute the UWP application package?

can someone please direct me to the right process? we are stuck here so any help would immensely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: An application developped using WinUI3 is not a UWP application. WinUI3 application deployment doesn't necessarily requires signing application. Choices (packages vs unpackaged, etc.) are explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/deploy-overview Make sure you're on the right path depending on your need, otherwise please add more details to your question.

Comment: @SimonMourier but still does not talk about how to package the winui3 app.  if we package as MSIX with dependencies when installing the MSIX, it says untrusted app. and i didn't see exact steps on packaging. can you please help me here?

Comment: Everything about WinUI3 packaging is in this documentation and articles. You'll have to be more precise than "how to package the app" for more help.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for help i will go through docs again thanks for help.